# Make HTML table wide enough to fit content

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I run a script that generates an HTML page, but I can't correctly format the table that is generated. need to make a table that spans as wide as necessary. Currently, I have to specify a specific width (1500px) so that the contents of each cell do not wrap to the next line. Here is an example:

```
With width set to 1500px:
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|Contents of my cell          | Contents of other cell       |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+

With width set to 100%:
+-------------------+--------------------+
|Contents of my     |Contents of other   |
|cell               |cell                |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Ideally, I the text wouldn't wrap (eg. when width is set to 1500px) but wouldn't have to set a static table width. At times, the table may need to be wider (or smaller) than 1500, so I would like the width to be as dynamic as possible.

This is the CSS I'm currently using:

```
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.796875) 0px 1px 0px;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman","Bitstream Charter",Times,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 7px 7px 8px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 24px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;-moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: Arial,"Bitstream Vera Sans",Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    width: 1500px;
}
th {
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.796875) 0px 1px 0px;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman","Bitstream Charter",Times,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 7px 7px 8px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #555;
}
td {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 7px 2px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-right: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
}
</style>
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Try adding ```html, body{ width: 100%;}``` to your css.  Wouldn't be surprised if it is because your body has no width.  Also make sure you have a declared doctype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to make it so the line never wraps, try white-space:nowrap and drop the width from your table.

```
td {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 7px 2px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-right: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! I don't work with CSS often, so I don't know about a lot of css properties.